# Box2d - Dynamic Sensors?

Tags: iphone, box2d

so I have this dynamic body, that I just want to know when an object collides with it, but even if this object collides with it, the dynamic body will always move at the same time and will only affect by gravity and the floor.

I tried kinmestic bodies and sensor, but it's not affected by gravity. I can add gravity but how can I add also that it will collide with the floor and stop?

I don't care what, but I most find a solution for that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for sensor in your case. You have to implement the b2ContactListener. Here is the manual how to do it: http://www.box2d.org/manual.html

Comment: Can you give me a pesudo code of how should I do that? I'm already working with b2ContactListener but I don't know how should I do that . .

Comment: @Eli: Take a look at paragraph 9 at the link i've given. There is the code you are looking for.

Comment: But still, how can I make the monsters not affected by the player at all? Just I need to know when it touches it.

Comment: @Eli: If you don't want some bodies to collide - take a look at b2Filter in the same manual

Comment: But there's another problem here - look, there are monsters, the player, and bullets. So the monsters are like background physics, they only say when there are contact points, they are not colliding with player and other monsters, but the bullets don't collide with the player and also the monsters, they only when there are contact points just send a callback. So it is possible? Big thanks!!

Comment: @Eli: try creating two fixtures on one b2Body. First one with correctly set up b2Filter not to collide with the bodies you don't want to, and the second one - sensor. So actually two totally the same fixtures, but one of them is a sensor and the second one is not

Comment: I have a problem with doing that - the monsters are sort of coming from the sky, so there must be gravity until the floor. That's why I don't use kinmestic.